# Serialized date and time string to DateTime object

Tags: c#, string, datetime, serialization, type-conversion

I have a serialized DateTime string which looks like this:

```
2010-04-14T16:32:06.75+10:00
```

What is the simplest way of deserializing/parsing it back into a DateTime?

Comment: @aJ - good comment :P I didn't event notice lack of language specified :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=VS.100).aspx)